# curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection

Tags: ssl, curl

on one of my servers i ran into an issue with SSLs, any CURL call to api.eu.mailgun.net:443 ends up with with an SSL error

```
curl --verbose https://api.eu.mailgun.net
*   Trying 34.95.107.114:443...
* Connected to api.eu.mailgun.net (34.95.107.114) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to api.eu.mailgun.net:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to api.eu.mailgun.net:443
```

SSLScan does not return any valid protocols:

```
sslscan https://api.eu.mailgun.net
Version: 2.0.7
OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022

Connected to 34.95.107.114

Testing SSL server api.eu.mailgun.net on port 443 using SNI name api.eu.mailgun.net

  SSL/TLS Protocols:
SSLv2     disabled
SSLv3     disabled
TLSv1.0   disabled
TLSv1.1   disabled
TLSv1.2   disabled
TLSv1.3   disabled

  TLS Fallback SCSV:
Connection failed - unable to determine TLS Fallback SCSV support

  TLS renegotiation:
Session renegotiation not supported

  TLS Compression:
OpenSSL version does not support compression
Rebuild with zlib1g-dev package for zlib support

  Heartbleed:

  Supported Server Cipher(s):
Certificate information cannot be retrieved.
```

Any help would be appreciated

This may be a helpful information:

- I have restored Hetzner cloud snapshot after few months
- Debian 11 Distro
- Time is up to date

Comment: What OS is the server using? Do you have date and time set up correctly on the server?

Comment: Debian 11, Yes I do

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, Hetzner has resolved the issue:

```
Unfortunately, some of our IPs are wrongly located in Iran by some GeoIP databases.
We cannot influence these databases.
```